# Open other applications with their Deeplinks in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

I am learning to have deep links in my application.

I would like to have my users link their social media, blog, or other site in my application.

But, it should attempt to open a link by detecting the site and attempt to open that site's application (at least for mainstream social media etc).

I was attempting to use https://github.com/BranchMetrics/Roots-iOS but their own demo does not even work it seems and I could not get my application to work(I am also using swift so I am not used to reading Obj-C too much).

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: A simple search for the words `deep linking in swift` returns a multitude of links. You should read through some articles and/or work through some tutorials and give it a try. If you run into specific *code* problems or questions, then come back and ask.

Comment: I have searched.  I have been reading articles and tutorials.  But they are almost all for creating deep links for my own application which I _don't need_.  I need to learn how to, from an web url, turn it into a deep link for that websites mobile application at minimum.  Many different sites use their own deep linking format and structure as there is **several** standards, and some people even just write their own and not care for the standard.  At least, according to the articles I have read. @DonMag

Comment: OK - perhaps I misunderstood your question... Are you looking for a list of URL schemes / universal links for other apps?

Comment: @DonMag that would certainly by helpful too.  If you look at the description for Roots-iOS that I linked, it says that all I need to do is pass a web url, like say facebook.com/<facebookId> (where the id is something like 10207864806639594) and it will instead generate the facebook deep link to open up the facebook app to that profile instead of opening the link via a browser.

Comment: if you have a list, I can probably write my own little Swift pod or cart instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it is not quite what i needed, the library https://github.com/SwiftKitz/Appz is pretty close.

It launches to an external application, with a web fall back.  It is also pretty easy to add code to pass a url and detect the base application and parse it out into that applications deeplinking scheme (which was info I didn't have before.)

Sorry for the trouble on this.